# Android: Using tiwlan0 to determine wireless connected status for Droid

Tags: android, wireless

I want to be able to check the status of Droid's wireless and I was hoping that by reading /sys/class/net/tiwlan0/wireless/status I could find out if it was actually connected or not. I already know that I can check if my wireless is enabled/disabled but I want my app to notify the user if the wireless gets disconnected.

However, the Droid I have is not rooted and I do not have permission from the owner to root it and I need to know the type of the value (e.g. long, boolean, byte) before I can proceed.

Any help or suggestions about other ways I can go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to listen to the `SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast. It will notify you of a change (scanning, association, disconnection, etc.) in the form of a `SupplicantState` object inside an extra.

Answer (score 0):

Install terminal emulater, run it and type the following at the command line: "`ifconfig -a`". Read the IP address listed under tiwlan0.